# Drupal -CMS export theme settings

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, themes, export

I build custom theme in Drupal (base theme Omega).
And try to export the theme settings.
As I clock on export theme settings, the message appears:
" This theme is not editable and therefore you won't be able to export the theme settings automatically. "

Any solutions?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got `locked = true` in your subtheme's info file.

Remove that line completely (don't just set it to `false`) and clear the caches - the error should disappear.